# Как посчитать все варианты заполнения прямоугольника состоящего из клеток

Tags: алгоритм

Количество клеток внутри прямоугольника неизвестно. Показал пример на 2 клетках

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет, не понятно

Comment: нужно закрасить клетки в прямоугольнике, всеми возможными способами

Comment: я сейчас предложу Вам как их карандашами закрасить, это тоже возможно

Comment: мне алгоритм лучше

Comment: я конечно же понял о чем речь, просто необходимо чтобы Вы научились сначала формулировать задачу, так и решать ее самому будет проще

Comment: есть двумерный массив(допустим 10 на 20). элементы массива могут иметь только 2 значения 1 и 0. Сколько существует различных вариантов этой матрицы? Такая формулировка пойдет?

Comment: Клетка может быть закрашена или не закрашена = 2 варианта. Если клеток N, получаем 2^N способов раскраски

Comment: @ДмитрийРатников вполне, поменяйте вопрос и может даже минусы ловить перестанете

Comment: @АндрейNOP а я посчитать не интерпретировал как сосчитать :), тем более Автор привел пример с раскладкой, я бы подумал что надо найти сами комбинации а не их количество

Comment: да нужны все варианты

Comment: @ДмитрийРатников серьезно? Вы привели пример матрицы 10х20, если это 2^200, скрипт сдохнет на полдороги))

Comment: через рекурсию?

Comment: Да вариантов тьма. Поясните хотя бы, в каком виде задаются ваши прямоугольники, как их вам выводить нужно. Надеюсь, не рисовать же? :)

Comment: я хочу светомузыку сделать, прямоугольная панель, там лампочки загораются. Играет музыка. И в ритм мигают лампочки

Answer (score 1):

По сути вам нужно получить все возможные подмножества данного множества клеток.

Самый простой вариант - для множества из N клеток (как вы их перенумеруете - дело ваше...) берем число из N битов, и проходим по всем возможным значениям числа (для 4 элементов - от 0000 до 1111, т.е. от 0 до 15). Далее для каждого числа рисуем крестики в клетках с номерами, соответствующими единицам - типа, для 0011 - третью и четвертую (или, поскольку удобнее и логичнее считать с младших битов, нулевую и первую :))